# How to detect if my Android app is connected to a Cromecast Audio or Video?

Tags: java, android, audio, streaming, chromecast

I have a cloud music player as an Android application and I recently added Chromecast support. The problem is some of the songs I have are lossless. Chromecast audio supports lossless streaming but classic Chromecast (the Video one) does not.

Is there a way in Android to detect if the Chromecast I am connected to is Chromecast Audio or not?

Answer (score 0):

I expect you'd be able to distinguish between the two based on the device capabilities exposed in the [CastDevice](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastDevice.html) class; try `CastDevice.hasCapability(int capability)` for the appropriate capability.